# goalseek vba finance model

Tags: excel, vba

need help with VBA code to goalseek project financing with the condition: IF the CF ending with period "n" (sourceRange) is negative, then GoakSeek the target value in the corresponding cell of the targetRange.

tried the VBA

```
Sub GSA()

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Set sourceRange = Range("W79:AT79")
    Set targetRange = Range("W154:AT154")

    For j = 1 To sourceRange.Columns.Count
      If sourceRange.Cells(1, j).Value < 0 Then
    PerformGoalSeekSub sourceRange.Cells(1, j), targetRange.Cells(1, j)
    End If
    Next j
End Sub

Sub PerformGoalSeekSub(SourceCell As Range,TargetCell As Range)
        TargetCell.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=SourceCell
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: When building financial model, there’s a circular reference in excel in cash ending. Solving this with VBA goalseek for those periods which have negative cash

Comment: That's your goal. It seems you still haven't explained what the current issue with the code is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GSA()
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim j As Integer

    Set sourceRange = Range("W79:AT79")
    Set targetRange = Range("W154:AT154")

    For j = 1 To sourceRange.Columns.Count
        If sourceRange.Cells(1, j).Value < 0 Then
            PerformGoalSeekSub sourceRange.Cells(1, j), targetRange.Cells(1, j)
        End If
    Next j
End Sub

Sub PerformGoalSeekSub(SourceCell As Range, TargetCell As Range)
     SourceCell.GoalSeek Goal:=0, changingCell:=TargetCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).